# Uploading Tile Packages to Apple Ipad

Tags: arcgis-field-maps, ipad, tile-package, apple

I work with a Environmental team that does a lot of work in the field using ESRI fieldmaps app. One thing they are always asking for is to have LiDAR or DEMs with the in the field. I make tpkx files for them to use and place it on their device to be used as a basemap. I know with android devices it's straight forward
-Plug in the device

- make sure it on "file sharing"
- in windows explorer navigate to the basemap folder of the field maps app in the mobile device.
- copy and paste the tpkx file from the desktop into the basemap folder of the mobile device.

When I try and do this on an apple product it never seems to work. I have tried using iTunes because that is where I have read that you can perform the same steps. When I plug in the apple product so that it is connected to a computer the file navigation doesn't appear. Am I missing a step with the apple product or is it something that just can't be done? Any help at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Officially

> "Files app (iOS)—Copy the basemap file (.tpk, .tpkx, or .vtpk) you
> want on your device to a website that is available in the Files app,
> for example, **iCloud Drive, Box, or Google Drive.** In the Files app,
> browse to where you uploaded the basemap file and copy it to your
> device, placing it in the Field Maps folder. See Apple Support for
> complete steps on using the Files app on your device."

should work - source https://doc.arcgis.com/en/field-maps/ios/use-maps/configure-field-maps.htm or would contact ESRI Support to assist.